# Some Drush master-branch commands report DB problem in Drupal 8

Tags: drush, 8

I use Drupal 8.0.0 in a Windows 10 home, WAMP environment.

When I run for example `drush up`, I get:

> The drush command 'up' could not be executed. Drush was not able to
>   start (bootstrap) the Drupal database

- Every action is done when I am in the sites folder (C:\wamp\www\sname>).
- This is a brand new environment - I've only one DB named equally as it's user.

### Update:

After I tried to follow this similar (but surly not identical!) thread, I added a fifth value to the Path Environment variable, restarted the Win CLI, and than when I ran `drush up` at the sites' folder, I got another, brand new error:

> wget nor curl executables found.

I need to further explore this but if you have an idea, please shoot...

**Drush status**

```
 C:\wamp\www\sname>drush status
 Drupal version         :  8.0.0
 Site URI               :  http://default
 Database driver        :  mysql
 Database hostname      :  localhost
 Database port          :  3306
 Database username      :  sname
 Database name          :  sname
 PHP executable         :  php.exe
 PHP configuration      :  C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini
 PHP OS                 :  WINNT
 Drush script           :  C:\drush-master\drush.php
 Drush version          :  8.1-dev
 Drush temp directory   :  C:\Users\Beni\AppData\Local\Temp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :
 Drupal root            :  C:\wamp\www\sname
 Site path              :  sites/default
 Sync config path       :  sites/default/files/config_mkuaR5uFQ7VCjh1_FFBuZzWXkUsz-sA7Klv4HO_2yLJG33wfJJabdavO7QKzyIRWiQoWA3IJbg/sync
```

**Drush sql-conf**

```
C:\wamp\www\sname>drush sql-conf
Array
(
    [database] => sname
    [username] => sname
    [prefix] => Array
        (
            [default] =>
        )

    [host] => localhost
    [port] => 3306
    [namespace] => Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql
    [driver] => mysql
)
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115158/drush-is-not-able-to-bootstrap?rq=1 ?

Comment: I humbly believe it isn't - besides the fact the environments are rather different, I tried to follow the solution there and I now get another error (Updated the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drush is giving a very accurate error message

> wget nor curl executables found.

You can either install Curl separately as benos suggests above or install more Unix tools. Since you might need Git anyway, why not install [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/)? Then you get a proper Bash prompt. If you prefer to use Command or Powershell you can select to update the PATH variable when installing so Git (and the Unix tools) are available there too.

Comment: I Benos, also asked the question :)

Comment: Can you please detail a bit more for Linux Layman like me why installing GIT is better than installing Composer or CURL each one separatly ? Does GIT contains them all? Thanks!!!

Comment: "Git for Windows" contains all the Unix/Linux tools that Drush and Git needs. Installing just Curl might be sufficient, but if you later discover that you need Git (and you really want to use version control) you have solved two problems at the same time. It's not really Git you need now, but "Git for Windows" contains the tools you need ;-)

Comment: Thank you for emphasizing what this is and that I don't need the regular version but something directly called "Git for Windows". Should I uninstall Drush and try it all from scratch? What you think? Oh and is it some kind of an "App manager" that would let me download&Install anything automatically our should I manually set everything including Environment variables, etc? This primal inf could help me plan my moves better.

Comment: "Git for Windows" is just a package containing Git **and** some Unix tools that (Git and) Drush also needs. There is no need to reinstall Drush. I'm just trying to suggest the best way to make both Drush and Git happy.

Answer (score 0):

This is due that for some reason Drush can't find your database. First make sure that your WAMP running on and your Drupal is been connected to a database. If you still have this problem you can try it out a Drush aliases, which is not ideal but it will solve your problem.

> You MUST create a local drush alias for the site using the following
>   for

```
<?php
/**
 * Local alias
 * Set the root and site_path values to point to your local site
 */
$aliases['yoursitename'] = array(
  'uri'  => 'http://yoursitename:8082',
  'root' => 'C:/Dev_Server/Dev_Sites/yoursitename',
  'db-url' => 'mysql://yourdatabaseusername:password@127.0.0.1:3306/yoursitename',
    'databases' =>
      array (
        'default' =>
        array (
          'default' =>
          array (
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'username' => 'yourdatabaseusername',
            'password' => 'yourpassword',
            'port' => '',
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'database' => 'yourdatabasename',
          ),
       ),
    ),
);
```

For a more details explanation of how to do this please refer to  - https://www.drupal.org/node/1393232#comment-9239657

Comment: A question to broaden the knowledge, please, and thanks in advance! --- Why do I must create the alias when In Drush 7.0.0 there was no such must?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me without creating a local Drush alias, was to install CURL for my 64-86 Windows 10 home environment, and than setting it's Path Environment variable (to CURL's bin folder).

Comment: Commenting after a long time: The best solution I can think of is to install VirtualBox with Ubuntu and raise up a Drupal environment from there --- I had other problems in Windows after the one I described upstairs and I can guarantee that as for 2016 Windows is not a suitable environment for working with Drush master and no solution \ Compatibility layer \ ready-to-go environment worked well as an actual virtual machine, for me, for running Drush master.

Comment: Prepare for some VirtualBox, Unix, and Ubuntu learning though... Can be fun, just stay away from bad non-didactic documentation or overtly long Youtube videos, and QA sites, internet forums, and Social media groups that inhibit cynical and sarcastic scumbags who might try to delude you they are there to help you...