# Drush is not able to bootstrap on Windows

Tags: drush

I'm having problems getting drush to bootstrap my site. My problems are similar to the one at "[Drush is not able to bootstrap](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115158/drush-is-not-able-to-bootstrap)". I asked this question once and it was put on hold, I guess because someone thought it was vague. Even though it was basically asking the same thing as this other guy.

Anyways, I tried all the suggestions from that link but I still get the same results.

- I'm running my Drupal 8 site on XAMPP on Windows 7.
- I'm running my Drush commands through Cygwin from C:\cygwin64
- root of site is C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal
- location of settings.php is C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\default
- I've added C:\xampp\php and C:\xampp\mysql\bin to my PATH run PHP and MYSQL respectively
- Contents of my settings.php

  ```
  $databases['default']['default'] = array (
    'database' => 'drupal_mydb',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'prefix' => '',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => '3306',
    'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
    'driver' => 'mysql',
  );
  $settings['install_profile'] = 'standard';
  $config_directories['sync'] = 'sites/default/files/config_ePqkB1ApPhBAjWSr1UBiDK8UDSGKZl08abHE6IbgZz15f5BPZZh2o7mTHHzcOMDLqbbLRyrRfg/sync';
  ```
- I've tried host with 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' and I get the same results.
- Regardless of the drush command, I always get "The system cannot find the path specified" output 5 times. Then it displays my site settings.
- When I run drush status -d, I receive this output:

  ```
  $ drush status -d
  The system cannot find the path specified.
  The system cannot find the path specified.
  The system cannot find the path specified.
  Drush could not detect the console window width. Set a Windows       [warning]
  Environment Variable of COLUMNS to the desired width. [0.34 sec, 1.85
  MB]
  The system cannot find the path specified.
  Cache HIT cid: 8.0.3-commandfiles-0-6c3f6dd05ff82c3c45e51e89444ebd0d     [debug]
  [0.47 sec, 1.9 MB]
  The system cannot find the path specified.
  Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.9 sec, 5 MB]                                [bootstrap]
  Trying to bootstrap as far as we can. [0.91 sec, 5 MB]                   [debug]
  Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.92 sec, 5.42 MB]  [bootstrap]
  The system cannot find the path specified.
  Initialized Drupal 8.0.3 root directory at C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal      [bootstrap]
  [1.03 sec, 5.42 MB]
  Find command files for phase 1 (max=7) [1.04 sec, 3.95 MB]               [debug]
  Cache HIT cid: 8.0.3-commandfiles-1-564685775c27b060bd0abf229ff308b6     [debug]
  [1.04 sec, 3.96 MB]
  Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_site() [1.07 sec, 4.55 MB]  [bootstrap]
  Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [1.07 sec, 4.55 MB] [bootstrap]
  The system cannot find the path specified.
  Find command files for phase 2 (max=7) [1.18 sec, 4.55 MB]               [debug]
  Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [1.18 sec,   [bootstrap]
  4.55 MB]
  Find command files for phase 3 (max=7) [1.19 sec, 4.69 MB]                [debug]
  sql-query: SELECT 1; [1.19 sec, 4.77 MB]                                [notice]
  Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file="C:\\cygwin64\\tmp\\druA347.tmp" --database=drupal_eldo --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 --silent  < "C:\\cygwin64\\tmp\\druA346.tmp"
  The system cannot find the path specified.
  1
  Bootstrap phase bootstrap_drupal_database() failed to validate;          [debug]
  continuing at bootstrap_drupal_configuration(). [1.3 sec, 4.77 MB]
  Found command: core-status (commandfile=core) [1.3 sec, 4.77 MB]     [bootstrap]
  Loading outputformat engine. [1.44 sec, 6.35 MB]                        [notice]
  Calling hook drush_core_status [1.45 sec, 6.38 MB]                       [debug]
  Returned from hook drush_core_status [3.32 sec, 6.4 MB]                  [debug]
   Drupal version         :  8.0.3
   Site URI               :  http://default
   Database driver        :  mysql
   Database hostname      :  127.0.0.1
   Database port          :  3306
   Database username      :  eldorado
   Database name          :  drupal_eldo
   PHP executable         :  php.exe
   PHP configuration      :  C:\xampp\php\php.ini
   PHP OS                 :  WINNT
   Drush script           :  C:\cygwin64\usr\local\src\drush-8.0.3\drush.php
   Drush version          :  8.0.3
   Drush temp directory   :  C:\cygwin64\tmp
   Drush configuration    :
   Drush alias files      :
   Drupal root            :  C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal
   Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php
   Site path              :  sites/default
   Sync config path       :  sites/default/files/config_ePqkB1ApPhBAjWSr1UBiDK8UD
                         SGKZl08abHE6IbgZz15f5BPZZh2o7mTHHzcOMDLqbbLRyrRfg/sy
                         nc
  ```

Any help?

**UPDATE**
This is an update of the message I receive. I have uninstalled XAMPP and deleted all files. I installed Acquia and a new site. I also updated my PATH to reflect the new configuration. I still get the same results.

```
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8>drush status -d -d
The system cannot find the path specified.
Drush preflight prepare loaded autoloader at C:\Program Files        [preflight]
(x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\autoload.php [0.12 sec, 1.71 MB]
Starting Drush preflight. [0.12 sec, 1.71 MB]                        [preflight]
Loading drushrc "C:\Program Files                                    [bootstrap]
(x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\drushrc.php" into "drush"
scope. [0.12 sec, 1.72 MB]
The system cannot find the path specified.
Cache HIT cid: 8.0.0-commandfiles-0-83c6f3e1f22ce6b4cd913212f7751c0a     [debug]
[0.26 sec, 1.76 MB]
Scanning into C:\ProgramData/Drush/etc/drush for                     [sitealias]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.38 sec, 3.45 MB]
Scanning into C:\ProgramData/Drush/etc/drush for                     [sitealias]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.38 sec, 3.45 MB]
Scanning into C:\Program Files                                       [sitealias]
(x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\includes/.. for
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.38 sec, 3.45 MB]
Scanning into C:\Program Files                                       [sitealias]
(x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\includes/.. for
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.59 sec, 3.45 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx/.drush for                            [sitealias]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.78 sec, 3.45 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx/.drush for                            [sitealias]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.78 sec, 3.45 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx/.acquia/DevDesktop/Drush/Aliases for  [sitealias]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.78 sec, 3.46 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx/.acquia/DevDesktop/Drush/Aliases for  [sitealias]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.78 sec, 3.46 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/../drush for [sitealias]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.78 sec, 3.46 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/../drush for [sitealias]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.78 sec, 3.46 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/drush for    [sitealias]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.78 sec, 3.46 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/drush for    [sitealias]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.78 sec, 3.46 MB]
Scanning into                                                        [sitealias]
C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/sites/all/drush for
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.78 sec, 3.46 MB]
Scanning into                                                        [sitealias]
C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/sites/all/drush for
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.78 sec, 3.46 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/sites/default[sitealias]
for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.78 sec, 3.46 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/sites/default[sitealias]
for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.79 sec, 3.46 MB]
The system cannot find the path specified.
Bootstrap to phase 0. [1.53 sec, 5.26 MB]                            [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_root() [1.57 sec, 5.69 MB]  [bootstrap]
The system cannot find the path specified.
Initialized Drupal 8.0.3 root directory at                              [notice]
C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8 [1.68 sec, 5.69 MB]
Find command files for phase 1 (max=7) [1.68 sec, 3.92 MB]               [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 8.0.0-commandfiles-1-e2a2f2754acb6b4934dbe6c8f3c38ac5     [debug]
[1.69 sec, 3.92 MB]
Scanning into C:\ProgramData/Drush/etc/drush for                     [sitealias]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [1.7 sec, 3.97 MB]
Scanning into C:\ProgramData/Drush/etc/drush for                     [sitealias]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [1.7 sec, 3.98 MB]
Scanning into C:\Program Files                                       [sitealias]
(x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\includes/.. for
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [1.7 sec, 3.98 MB]
Scanning into C:\Program Files                                       [sitealias]
(x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\includes/.. for
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [1.91 sec, 3.98 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx/.drush for                            [sitealias]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [2.09 sec, 3.98 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx/.drush for                            [sitealias]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [2.09 sec, 3.98 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx/.acquia/DevDesktop/Drush/Aliases for  [sitealias]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [2.09 sec, 3.98 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx/.acquia/DevDesktop/Drush/Aliases for  [sitealias]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [2.1 sec, 3.98 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/../drush for [sitealias]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [2.1 sec, 3.98 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/../drush for [sitealias]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [2.1 sec, 3.98 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/drush for    [sitealias]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [2.1 sec, 3.98 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/drush for    [sitealias]
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [2.1 sec, 3.98 MB]
Scanning into                                                        [sitealias]
C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/sites/all/drush for
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [2.1 sec, 3.98 MB]
Scanning into                                                        [sitealias]
C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/sites/all/drush for
/self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [2.1 sec, 3.99 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/sites/default[sitealias]
for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [2.1 sec, 3.99 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/sites/default[sitealias]
for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [2.1 sec, 3.99 MB]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_site() [2.13 sec, 4.52 MB]  [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [2.13 sec, 4.52 MB]    [notice]
The system cannot find the path specified.
Find command files for phase 2 (max=7) [2.24 sec, 4.52 MB]               [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [2.24 sec,  [bootstrap]
4.52 MB]
Find command files for phase 3 (max=7) [2.27 sec, 4.67 MB]               [debug]
sql-query: SELECT 1; [2.3 sec, 4.75 MB]                                 [status]
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file="C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\
abase=drupal8 --host=localhost --port=33067 --silent  < "C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppD
ru4CD2.tmp"
The system cannot find the path specified.
  1
Found command: core-status (commandfile=core) [3.52 sec, 4.75 MB]    [bootstrap]
Loading outputformat engine. [3.93 sec, 6.62 MB]                        [notice]
Calling hook drush_core_status [3.97 sec, 6.65 MB]                       [debug]
Scanning into C:\ProgramData/Drush/etc/drush for                     [sitealias]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [3.97 sec, 6.66 MB]
Scanning into C:\ProgramData/Drush/etc/drush for                     [sitealias]
/.*\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [3.97 sec, 6.66 MB]
Scanning into C:\Program Files                                       [sitealias]
(x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\includes/.. for
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [3.97 sec, 6.66 MB]
Scanning into C:\Program Files                                       [sitealias]
(x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\includes/.. for
/.*\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [4.19 sec, 6.66 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx/.drush for                            [sitealias]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [4.38 sec, 6.66 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx/.drush for                            [sitealias]
/.*\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [4.38 sec, 6.66 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx/.acquia/DevDesktop/Drush/Aliases for  [sitealias]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [4.38 sec, 6.66 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx/.acquia/DevDesktop/Drush/Aliases for  [sitealias]
/.*\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [4.38 sec, 6.67 MB]
Scanning into c:\users\xxx\sites\devdesktop\drupal8\drush for    [sitealias]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [4.38 sec, 6.67 MB]
Scanning into c:\users\xxx\sites\devdesktop\drupal8\drush for    [sitealias]
/.*\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [4.38 sec, 6.67 MB]
Scanning into                                                        [sitealias]
c:\users\xxx\sites\devdesktop\drupal8\sites\all\drush for
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [4.38 sec, 6.67 MB]
Scanning into                                                        [sitealias]
c:\users\xxx\sites\devdesktop\drupal8\sites\all\drush for
/.*\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [4.38 sec, 6.67 MB]
Scanning into c:\users\xxx\sites\devdesktop\drupal8\sites\default[sitealias]
for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [4.38 sec, 6.67 MB]
Scanning into c:\users\xxx\sites\devdesktop\drupal8\sites\default[sitealias]
for /.*\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [4.39 sec, 6.67 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/../drush for [sitealias]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [4.39 sec, 6.67 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/../drush for [sitealias]
/.*\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [4.39 sec, 6.67 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/drush for    [sitealias]
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [4.39 sec, 6.67 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/drush for    [sitealias]
/.*\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [4.39 sec, 6.67 MB]
Scanning into                                                        [sitealias]
C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/sites/all/drush for
/.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [4.39 sec, 6.68 MB]
Scanning into                                                        [sitealias]
C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/sites/all/drush for
/.*\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [4.39 sec, 6.68 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/sites/default[sitealias]
for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [4.39 sec, 6.68 MB]
Scanning into C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8/sites/default[sitealias]
for /.*\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [4.4 sec, 6.68 MB]
Returned from hook drush_core_status [4.4 sec, 6.68 MB]                  [debug]
 Drupal version      :  8.0.3
 Site URI            :  http://default
 Database driver     :  mysql
 Database hostname   :  localhost
 Database port       :  33067
 Database username   :  drupaluser
 Database name       :  drupal8
 PHP executable      :  php.exe
 PHP configuration   :  "C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\php5_5\php.ini"
 PHP OS              :  WINNT
 Drush script        :  C:\Program Files
                        (x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\drush.php
 Drush version       :  8.0.0
 Drush temp          :  C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp
 directory
 Drush               :  "C:\Program Files
 configuration          (x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\drushrc.php"
 Drush alias files   :  C:\Users\xxx/.acquia/DevDesktop/Drush/Aliases/alias
                        es.drushrc.php
 Drupal root         :  C:\Users\xxx\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8
 Site path           :  sites/default
 Sync config path    :  sites/drupal8.dd/files/config__MU_PbJKL0CkmmcMAh-3pssQv
                           pfSqcF9o4_8g3U2BvK9vhbajglchlm0aNTYERfuA69tkkyaGw/sync

Command dispatch complete [4.55 sec, 6.77 MB]                           [notice]
```

As you can see even before I enter the drush status -d -d command I already receive the "The system cannot find the path specified" error.

Comment: I got unsure - does Drush work or not? Anyway, "The system cannot find the path specified." means that Windows can't find the command/file that Drush tries to run. It can be because you are missing something in your Cygwin installation or a bug in Drush (when used together with Cygwin). I would add another -d to the command to see if that reveals which command causes the message.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like Drush is working. However anytime I run any command (even outside of the site root directory) I get "The system cannot find the path specified", followed by some PHP info. For instance from C drive I get this:
`The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
PHP executable:php.exe
PHP configuration:C:\xampp\php\php.ini
PHP OS:WINNT
Drush script:C:\cygwin64\usr\local\src\drush-8.0.3\drush.php
Drush version: 8.0.3
Drush temp directory :C:\cygwin64\tmp
Drush configuration
Drush alias files`

Comment: The weird thing is that when I click on the _shell_ button in the XAMPP control panel, the command prompt that appears also shows "The system cannot find the path specified" twice. Followed by "Setting environment for using XAMPP for Windows".

Comment: The last observation indicates strongly that the problem is related to XAMPP - not Drush. Maybe ask in a XAMPP forum? I don't use XAMPP myself anymore. I switched to [http://www.ampps.com/](AMPPS) and then to Acquia Dev Desktop where I know Drush works ;-)

Comment: I did a complete uninstall of XAMPP. I installed Acquia Dev Desktop, per your suggestion, and I followed their instructions step for step. I still get the same results when I run Drush through the Acquia console.

Comment: So what do "drush status -d" say when you run it through the ADD console? And AFAICT you haven't tried adding another "-d" to see if you get more info - as I suggested in my first comment. Tracking down problems/bugs is hard work ;-)

PS! Update the question with the new output from drush status. Reading it as a comment is hard.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. Yes, I tried adding the other -d when I run drush status, but I get the exact same thing as when I run it with only one -d. When I run it from the root of my site I still get the "site not bootstrapped" error. When I run it from anywhere else, I get the "The system cannot find the path specified" error right off the top. I made sure drush.bat was referencing the correct PHP, made sure Mysql was running, tried changing from "localhost" to "127.0.01", but each time I get the same results. I've updated my original question like you suggested.

Comment: Doing debugging remotely is difficult, but to track it down you need to minimize the code that runs. In "C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\drush\drush.bat" put "echo" in front of @php.exe (on line 25 or so). If you still get the "The system cannot find the path specified." message, you know that that problem isn't related to Drush. It's a Windows problem.

Comment: Yeah, I think it is a Windows problem. I had tried that adding a simple test to the drush.bat file, like you had suggested, and yes I still get the same error message. Plus I had a co-worker, who has the same computer setup as me, try the same thing and he gets Drush to work correctly. So I guess there's something in my computer that is causing this. I'll have to do some digging around. One last question, where would be a good place to start looking?? I know I have a long way to debug this, so any help would be appreciated. Thanx so much for all your help.

Comment: My best suggestion is [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=batch+script+"The+system+cannot+find+the+path+specified.") but this seems to be a hard problem to track down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot update modules with drush – needs higher bootstrap level](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/242951/cannot-update-modules-with-drush-needs-higher-bootstrap-level)